# Would Firefox 3.5.8 freezing on Windows 7 indicate a problem with Windows WiFi driver or with Firefox?

Tags: windows-7, firefox

I recently installed Windows 7 in spite of a lack of driver support from my laptop manufacturer but somehow Windows 7 seemed to be able to figure out what was needed - including the WiFi driver.

But after I installed Firefox 3.5.8, I found that Firefox freezes frequently. When this happens the whole Windows interface turns sort of whitish like it's disabling interaction and, indeed, you cannot interact with anything in Windows. After a few minutes the freeze resolves itself and everything returns to normal. I scanned for viruses and ran the defragenter but nothing seems unusual besides these freezes.

Anyone have any ideas what might be causing it and whether it's likely a problem with Firefox or with Windows - or perhaps with the hardware or drivers (WiFi driver?)?

Comment: Do you have a wired connection you can use? If you do then perform the same actions as you would normally. If Firefox freezes then it's not a WiFi issue. If it doesn't then it's likely that it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take a look at an article called [**Firefox hangs**](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_hangs) at mozillaZine.  There are lots of *potential* fixes to this problem.

I would also have a quick peek in your event logs and check for any obvious warnings or errors.  That may well point you in the right direction as to what is locking your computer up.

[image]

To get to your event viewer, click the Start button, type `event` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.